# Is it safe to call Screen.hide() after Screen.dispose() in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, game-engine

In libgdx, `screen.setScreen()` doesn't call dispose automatically right. Inside a overridden setScreen, do I have to call `screen.dispose` first and then call `super.setScreen` or call the later first?
I know this may seem like duplicate question but still I wanted to know because `super.setScreen` calls `screen.hide`. Is calling `hide` after `dispose` run-time safe?
Is it a bad practice?
I am making a 3D game based on [this](http://www.kilobolt.com/unit-1-building-the-game.html) and [this](https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/learning-libgdx-game-development-second-edition) example .
Here I am extending `GameName` class by `Game` and trying to override `setScreen` so as to call dispose if screen is not null and then call `super.setScreen` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screen.dispose()` is never called by LibGDX. You must do it manually yourself before dropping the reference to your screen. If you don't plan to reuse the Screen instance, having `screen.hide()` call `screen.dispose()` is the perfect place to do it.

`screen.hide()` is never called in response to Android events.

I don't recommend overriding `game.setScreen()` to dispose of screens unless you know for sure you never want to reuse any screen instances. In most simple games, you do want to reuse them rather than waste time unloading and reloading assets repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Two type of disposable assets(SpriteBatch, Texture, Stage, ...), one is shared on different screen and another one is specific for particular screen.

1. Shared Assets should be disposed from Game's `dispose()` method.
2. Screen specific assets should be disposed through `dispose()` method of Screen but screen's dispose() never called so you need to call it explicitly.

When you change your screen `hide()` method of Screen called so you should call `dispose()` method from `hide()` method.

Comment: But in Android hide gets called when the user gets a call or game lose focus. So adding dispose inside hide is bad idea.

Comment: @Anutrix what do think Screen's hide() method call Android's hide(). Both are different method.

Comment: @Anutrix, No, it doesn't. `pause()` gets called when the game loses focus, but not `hide()`.